# Implicit Differentiation of an Inner Product to find Jacobian

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inner-products, matrix-equations

Let there be a mapping, $x \mapsto y(x)$, an SPD matrix $A$, and some constant $m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the following holds:

$(y-m)^T A(y-m)/2 = x^Tx/2$.

I need to find the Jacobian of the mapping, $J = \partial y/\partial x$. Using the Matrix Cookbook, after differentiating both sides by $x$, I find

$$A(y-m)\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = x.$$

The first question is whether I applied the chain rule correctly there. It is not clear from the sources I used. The second question is how to find $J$ given the above. From the above, the only option appears to be a scalar, which gives me pause.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Cholesky decomposition of the matrix one can write
$$\eqalign{
A &= C^TC \\ 
x &= C(y-m) \\
}$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{
dx &= C\,dy \\
dy &= C^{-1}\,dx \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} &= C^{-1} \\
}$$